# Routine to work out if today is a trading day on the NYSE?

Tags: c#, trading, algorithmic-trading

Does anyone know of a routine that works out if today is a trading day on the NYSE?

I could hand-code the values, but I want something solid that will last a long time.

There is a routine in Matlab, but I'd rather not have to install 100MB of Matlab runtimes and a C#-to-Matlab bridge.

Comment: Do you have the source of the MATLAB routine?

Comment: Yes - the source is provided as part of the standard Matlab install if you include the financial libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask your broker. My data feed gives me the trading hours for the next few days for all exchanges I subscribe to on a daily basis.

Comment: Nice - what data feed do you use? I'm using IQfeed.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a routine, and want to unit test it, the trading days for the NYSE are listed from 1885 to 2010 here:

http://www.chronos-st.org/NYSE_Observed_Holidays-1885-Present.html

Edit: Page disappeared, see here:

https://web.archive.org/web/2019*/http://chronos-st.org/NYSE_Observed_Holidays-1885-Present.html